# "FizzBuzz"-style program that checks for divisibility by multiple numbers prints numbers multiple times when it should print words

Tags: python

In a range of numbers from 1-100
This code should print:

- `Fizz` if the number is divisible by 3
- `Buzz` if the number is divisible by 5
- `Bizz` if the number is divisible by 7
- `FizzBuzz` if the number is divisible by 3 and 5
- Similarly, all cases of `Fizz`, `Buzz` and `Bizz` combined depending on divisibility
- The number itself if none of the above apply

```
n = 0
toTest = [
    3,
    5,
    7
]
outputCanBe = [
    "Fizz",
    "Buzz",
    "Bizz"
]
outputIndex = 0
iteration = (len(toTest)) 
while n <= 100:
    n += 1
    output = ""
    for num in range(iteration):
        if n%toTest[num] == 0:
            outputIndex = num
            output += outputCanBe[outputIndex]
        else:
            output += str(n)  
        print(output)
        output = ""
```

In  the `for num in range(iteration)`, the code loops through the checker multiple times to perform all divisibility tests. Due to a logical error that I can't catch, my code repeatedly prints the number, as shown below

```
2
2
2
Fizz
3
3
4
4
4
```

The expected output is:

```
2
Fizz
4
```

and so on...

Comment: You need to process ALL the numbers in `iteration` before deciding what to output.  But your code makes output after EACH number.

Comment: Umm, what do you mean by this?

Comment: You are appending n to output every time you check the modulo. Check the modulo for each case and then append.

Comment: When looping over `3 5 7` to decide what to output, you're supposed to print `n` if it wasn't divisible by ANY of those numbers.  But you're printing `n` if it wasn't divisible by 3, AND you're printing `n` if it wasn't divisible by 5, AND you're printing `n` if it wasn't divisible by 7.  You have to wait until the END of that loop to print anything.

Comment: you are checking for all the 3 values of toTest and printing the output immediatley in that block scope. whereas it should be out of that block scope and should be printed when all values are evaluated.

Comment: Oh, so the ```else``` should actually be outside the scope of the if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the "Fizz" "Buzz" "Bizz" if the division is possible, at the end if nothing has been added, it means that you have to print the number itself.

```
n = 0
toTest = [
    3,
    5,
    7
]
outputCanBe = [
    "Fizz",
    "Buzz",
    "Bizz"
]
outputIndex = 0
iteration = (len(toTest)) 
while n <= 25:
    n += 1
    output = ""
    for num in range(iteration):
        if n%toTest[num] == 0:
            outputIndex = num
            output += outputCanBe[outputIndex]
    if not output:
        print(n)
    else:
        print(output)
```

**EDIT :**

Here's a cleaner and shorter version :

```
words = {3: "Fizz", 5: "Buzz", 7: "Bizz"}
size = 100
for n in range(size):
    output = ""
    for (numb, word) in words.items():
        if n % numb == 0:
            output += word
    print(n) if not output else print(output)
```

I used a *dictionnary* to connect a `numb` (example : 3) and its `word` (example : "Fizz").

Doing a `for` loop is just for shorter code.

The `.items()` method is meant to unpack the `(key,value)` of a *dictionnary*.

Python consider that if a `str` is empty its `bool` value is `False`. If it's not empty, no matter what it contains it's `True`. That's what the `if not ouput` is for, to check if `output` is empty (divided by none of these numbers) or not.